# PHP dynamic URL variables in curly braces

Tags: javascript, php, html, string, url

I need to check if a route exists, the routes in the array are strings, the routes are stored in an array of strings e.g. routes[0] = 'posts/all/{postID}' (notice the curly braces and parameter name). Let's say the user enters the site with url 'post/all/4'. How is it possible to match the url entered in browser to the one with curly braces and parameter name and, if there is one matching in the array, call a function that gets only the part of url before the parameter in curly braces and pass the variable inside braces with it's original name to this function (can be an array, e.g. params['postID']=4)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a basic version that might help. First it turns your path and variables into regular expressions. Then it checks the incoming url against each of them in turn. If it finds a match, it passes the path and variable to your url function.

```
$incomingUrl = 'posts/all/123';
$routes = ['posts/all/{postID}', 'users/all/{userID}', 'pasta/all/{pastaID}'];

// Parse your url templates into regular expressions.
$routeRegexes = [];
foreach ($routes as $route) {
    $parts = [];
    $partsRegex = '`(.+?){(.+?)}`';
    preg_match($partsRegex, $route, $parts);
    $routeRegexes[] = [
        'path' => $parts[1], 
        'varName' => $parts[2],
        'routeRegex' => "`($parts[1])(.+)`"
    ];
}
print_r($routeRegexes);

// Check the incoming url for a match to one of your route regexes.    
$urlMatch = null;
foreach ($routeRegexes as $routeRegex) {
    if (preg_match($routeRegex['routeRegex'], $incomingUrl, $urlMatch)) {
        $routeRegex['varValue'] = $urlMatch['2'];
        $urlMatch = $routeRegex;
        break;
    }
}
print_r($urlMatch);

if (!empty($urlMatch)) {
    $path = $urlMatch['path'];
    $variableName = $urlMatch['varName'];
    $variableValue = $urlMatch['varValue'];
    echo "Path: $path\n";
    echo "Variable name: $variableName\n";
    echo "Variable value: $variableValue\n";

    // Pass the variables to your url function.
    // callUrl($path, [$variableName => $variableValue]);
} else {
    // Throw 404 path not found error.
}
```

Hope this points you in the right direction.

Comment: No problem. I think if you accept the answer by clicking on the grey tick, it will give us both some reputation.